# Convertir Date a String en java

Tags: java, string, date

Estoy consumiendo un servicio web donde consulto por un parámetro id, y me devuelve un objeto *vehículo* que contiene varios atributos tipo `int` y `string`, pero el campo *fecha* me lo devuelve como date.

"asi esta en la base de datos", lo que necesito es poder convertir ese atributo a `string` para poder imprimirlo por un formulario.

He seguido lo que ustedes me dijeron y me saca un error.

El método es este:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ServiciosVehiculosService AAA = new ServiciosVehiculosService();
    ServiciosVehiculos BBB = AAA.getServiciosVehiculosPort();
    ViewVEHICULOWEB XVARIABLEX = new ViewVEHICULOWEB();
    XVARIABLEX.setPLACA("QYA456");
    ViewVEHICULOWEB XXX = BBB.consultarViewVehiculoWeb(XVARIABLEX);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(XXX.getFECHAREG()));
}
```

Y el error este:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
>   (default-cli) on project ProyectoWeb: Command execution failed.
>   Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: Luego de la edición, tu problema es de compilación con Maven, directamente asociado al plugin de org.codehaus.mojo (del cual no tengo la más remota idea). Te comento que ese problema de maven es distinto al problema que planteaste al inicio.

Answer (score 3):

Usa `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String fechaComoCadena = sdf.format(new Date());
System.out.println(fechaComoCadena);
```

Comment: Ese codigo lo busque en internet, y no se en que parte envio el atributo de esta forma XvariableX.getFecha();

Comment: Date date = formatter.parse(variable.getFecha());
String fechaComoCadena = sdf.format(date);
Así pasas la fecha a date, teniendo en cuenta que tu getFecha es un string, si es un date, solo ponlo en lugar del new Date()

Answer (score 1):

Hola como ya lo dijo Luggi, utiliza SimpleDateFormat  para  mostrar las fechas en el formato que desees o a reconstruirla a partir de una cadena de texto.
Su ejemplo más básico es:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

// Esto muestra la fecha actual en pantalla, más o menos así 28/03/2017
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Desde luego puedes modificar la mascara de la fecha para que la salida sea en otro formato como AAAA-DD-MM , AA-MM-DD, etc.

Para mayor referencia siempre es recomendable leer la documentación oficial  y por supuesto buscar antes un poco.

[SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Que pena tanta molestia, pero el codigo que ustedes me comparten me imprime fecha actual del sistema, pero lo que yo necesito es que me convierta el valor de la fecha que me llega desde la base de datos, no se en donde incluirlo en el codigo

Comment: El código que se te comparte es la implementación más básica, en esta parte de codigo deberas  pasar el objeto Date :
sdf.format(miObjeto.getMifechaRecibida());
Lee un poco la documentación oficial para entender como funciona.

Comment: Sólo tienes que cambiar el new Date() por tu campo Date que quieres convertir a String

Comment: añado mas informacion acerca del error, la forma que ustedes me compartieron ya la habia hecho

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se genera el cliente de un servicio web de tipo SOAP y éste contiene tipos de datos *`xsd:date`*, éstos se *mapean*, por defecto, al tipo  [`javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) de Java.

De acuerdo con [*§2.3. Usando diferentes tipo de datos*](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Using_different_datatypes.html) (en inglés):

> XMLGregorianCalendar está diseñado para ser 100% compatible con el sistema fecha/hora del esquema XML, tal como proporcionar precisión infinita en sub-segundos y años, pero a menudo la facilidad de uso de las clases  familiares de Java ganan sobre la compatibilidad precisa.

Por lo que es necesario hacer una conversión a `java.util.Date` si se quiere utilizar una instancia de `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. Es decir:

```java
java.util.Date date = XXX.getFECHAREG().toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```